# chartJs replace 0 with datas

Tags: angular, chart.js

Hello everyone I'm making a chart with default 0 data's.Then I'd like to replace all 0 values with my variables.

**JS**

```
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'doughnut',
  data: {
    labels: ['lbl1', 'lbl2', 'lbl3', 'lbl4', 'lbl5'],
    datasets: [{
      data: [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
      backgroundColor: [
        'rgba(0, 119, 204, 0.8)',
        'rgba(0, 119, 204, 0.7)',
        'rgba(0, 119, 204, 0.6)',
        'rgba(0, 119, 204, 0.4)',
        'rgba(0, 119, 204, 0.3)'
      ],
    }]
  },
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    legend: false,

    tooltips: {
      callbacks: {
        label: function (t, d) {
          var isSame = d.datasets[t.datasetIndex].data.every(function (e) {
            return e === 1;

          });
          if (isSame) return d.labels[t.index] + ': ' + 0;
          else return d.labels[t.index] + ': ' + d.datasets[t.datasetIndex].data[t.index];

        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

It makes all the values at the beginning 0 and equal part the chart.Now I have variables like counter1, counter2...counter5 I'd like to replace with 0's.
How can I do that.

Thank you

Comment: ChartJs and yes I want to add [counter1, counter2....] they are length numbers

Comment: no I ll put a simple if condition if not all the counters are not 0 datas are counters else 0